# Add total line count to end of file bash

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, grep, wc

I have two statements in bash that I would like to combine so that the output is all in one file.  Would there be a way to combine these?  What the second line is basically doing is adding a total line count to the bottom of the file.  I would like it to line up with the formatting of the file which is why I would like to combine the two somehow.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
grep -E -o -r "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" $ARCHIVE | sed 's/.*@//' | sort -r | uniq -ic | sort -nr | sed 's/^ *//g' | awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } ' | column -t > temp2



echo Total "$(wc -l < temp2)"
```

Comment: Stop. You never need a chain of 20 commands and pipes to manipulate text. All you need is one clear, simple, awk command to do what that chain of pipes is doing and then tweaking it to add a line count at the end is absolutely trivial. If you post some sample input (i.e. contents of $ARCHIVE) and expected output then we can help you. I won't critique everything you already have but just wrt `{ t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; }` - a simple `{print $2, $1}` would work.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` does a good job of keeping track of the number of lines.  Replace

```
awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; }'
```

With:

```
awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } END{print "Total",NR}'
```

In awk, `NR` is the number of records (lines) that have been read.  The `END` block is executed only after all the lines have been read.  Thus, this puts the total count at the end of the file, eliminating the need for the final `echo Total "$(wc -l < temp2)"` statement.

Comment: Better yet, replace the whole pipeline with an Awk script.  It just counts the number of unique domain names in (what amounts to a rough approximation of) email addresses.

Comment: @EdMorton (a) The OP wrote _"I would like it to line up with the formatting of the file"_.  So, yes, affecting the final `column -t` was the goal.  (b) Yours and Tripleee's suggestion regarding the whole of the pipeline is, of course, correct.  But, as you noted above, the OP has provided neither sample input nor desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
| column -t > temp2
```

with

```
| column -t | tee temp2 | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any sample input to test against or even see, this is obviously untested and includes some guess work but it is basically the right approach (using GNU awk and assuming "$ARCHIVE" is a directory):

```
find "$ARCHIVE" -type f -print |
xargs awk '
BEGIN { FPAT="[[:alnum:]_%+-]+@[[:alnum:]_%+-]+[.][[:alpha:]]{2,6}" }
{
    $0 = tolower($0)
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        sub(/.*@/,"",$i)
        cnt[$i]++
        width = (length($i) < width ? width: length($i))
    }
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_val_desc"
    for (host in cnt) {
        printf "%-*s %s\n", width, host, cnt[host]
    }
    printf "%-*s %s\n", width, "Total", length(cnt)
}'
```